# Angular2 nested components variables not accessible in template

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

Iv'e recently started playing around with Angular2, and face a pretty basic issue.

I'm trying to create a simple parent component that is simply a container of dynamic boxes.
Each box has it's own properties and data.

What Iv'e done so far is the following:

**The container class:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from 'ionic-angular';
import {MainBox} from './../../component/main-box/main-box.component';

@Component({
  selector      :   'wrapper',
  templateUrl   :   'build/component/main-container/main-container.component.html',
  directives    :   [IONIC_DIRECTIVES, MainBox]
})

export class MainContainer {
  boxes : MainBox[] = [
    {title : "mor"},
    {title : "naama"}
  ];
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

**The container template**

```
<div>
    <main-box *ngFor="let box of boxes"></main-box>
</div>
```

** main-box stands for each individual box

**MainBox class:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector      :   'main-box',
  templateUrl   :   'build/component/main-box/main-box.component.html',
  directives    :   [IONIC_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class MainBox {
  title:any;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**Box Template**

```
{{title}}
```

I would expect that Angular will automatically display the right title, but in fact it shows nothing.

On the other hand, if I do the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let box of boxes">{{box.title}}</div>
```

I can see the title just fine, but it's not good enough for me since I wish to completely separate the template files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass data explicitly to children:

```
<div>
    <main-box *ngFor="let box of boxes" [title]="box.title"></main-box>
</div>
```

```
export class MainBox {
  @Input()title:any;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: So I must do that for every attribute? is there a better practice to achieve my goals?

Comment: You can pass `box` to the template instead of `box.title` and then use `{{box.title}}` or `{{box?.title}}` in the box template instead of just `{{title}}`

Comment: Thanks, I would really appreciate an example though :)

Comment: If you have multiple attributes and a child tree a few levels deep, you may want to have your data in a service. The @Input works fine for child components, but falls apart quickly if you have more than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the title in the main box if you provide the title as an input to it

```
   <div *ngFor="let box of boxes">
             <main-box [title]="box.title"></main-box>
   </div>
```

Comment: There is no need to move `*ngFor` to a parent element. Title needs to be an input for `[title]="box.title"` to work (see my answer).

Comment: yes i just checked ngfor would work in main box too thanks